# SCPI_ParamString multiple string as input

Tags: microcontroller, pic24

I am using the SCPI library of commands, namely SCPI_ParamString. The function I am trying to implement takes in 2 strings and an integer as inputs. To verify that my code is reading the inputs correctly, I am having it simply print my inputs back out to me (I will pass these along to the function once I am confident I am using the right strings).

What I've found is that my code doesn't identify the comma as a delineator between two inputs. It prints all 3 inputs as the first string. What is interesting, is that when I ask it to print the second input - it recognizes that the comma delineates between first and second input. So it prints only the second and third input (not recognizing the comma between 2nd and 3rd as separating inputs.

I am coding on a PIC24, in C using MPLABX IDE v3.15.

Below is my code followed by example output.

```
const char * longstr1;
const char * longstr2;
size_t ls1_len = 80;
size_t ls2_len = 80;
scpi_bool_t mandat = 1;
int32_t deltamin;

    if (!SCPI_ParamString(context, &longstr1, &ls1_len, mandat) ) 
    {
        return SCPI_RES_ERR;
    }
    if (!SCPI_ParamString(context, &longstr2, &ls2_len, mandat) )
    {
        return SCPI_RES_ERR;
    }
    if (!SCPI_ParamInt(context, &deltamin, mandat))
    {
        return SCPI_RES_ERR;
    } 
    sprintf(strTmp,"Inputs:" STR_CRLF);
    uart1_puts(strTmp);
    sprintf(strTmp,longstr1);
    uart1_puts(strTmp);
    sprintf(strTmp,STR_CRLF);
    uart1_puts(strTmp);
    sprintf(strTmp,longstr2 );
    uart1_puts(strTmp);
```

And sample execution:

```
SCPI|0x51> GPS:PROP SGP4,1 00005U 58002B   00179.78495062  .00000023  00000-0  28098-4  0 4753,2 00005  34.2682 348.7242 1859667 331.7664  19.3264 10.824191574136                                                67,360
SCPI|0x51> Inputs:
1 00005U 58002B   00179.78495062  .00000023  00000-0  28098-4  0 4753,2 00005  34.2682 348.7242 1859667 331.7664  19.3264 10.82419157413667,360

2 00005  34.2682 348.7242 1859667 331.7664  19.3264 10.82419157413667,360
0)00:20:53:58.43 task_supmcu_scpi:      Accepted "GPS:PROP SGP4,1 00005U 58002B   00179.78495062  .00000023  00000-0  28098-4  0 4753,2 00005  34.2682 348.7242 1859667 331.7664  19.3264 10.82419157413667,360" command.
```

Notice that when I print the first input all 3 inputs are actually printed, and when I print the second the second and third are actually printed.

I've tried a few different things to get around this - none have worked.